# Randomizing questions from SQL table for VB.NET (examination system)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm actually having a hard time figuring out the logic for this form. I have the questions and the choices in my SQLtable. 
And here's my query to randomize questions in the SQL SMS:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Seniors.dbo.Math ORDER BY newID()
```

What I'm actually confused is that how should I be able to generate these questions to the form?

[image: Form pic in the lower part of the pic]

PS: It's actually '10', not '25' in the query part. Forgot to edit, sorry zzz

Comment: Are you asking how to retrieve records from Sql Server using VB.NET?

Comment: Yes sir, but how should I be able to randomize it in the vb.net form without repetition? and how should I code the process of identifying which is the correct answer?

Comment: That Sql Command already randomize your questions correctly, what do you need is an ADO.NET Tutorial on how to retrieve these records and use them in your application. For example this is the first link coming out on a search engine: http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/database/

Comment: Cant I really manipulate these data into one vb form?

Comment: Are there any other ways to generate questions, aside from storing them in the database?

Comment: Selecting a random row from the DB wont prevent the same Question from coming up more than once in a game.  Load all the IDs, put them in random order, then SELECT them one by one for the quiz...or load all the data and shuffle and select from a DataTable using linq